# Hold  ajax call in every minute calling section

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am calling **ajax every second** in page.. 
Here the server page returns **randomly generated number**,using this number(**converted into seconds**) i am **triggering** another function in **ajax success**  .it works

My problem

suppose **random number = 5** means **trigger() function** called **after 5 seconds** using **setTimeout**,but rember  ajax call is triggering every 1 second so trigger function also called many time.

i want to make **ajax call wait untill trigger function execution**.Which means i wanna pause that ajax call untill 5 seconds after that resume

How can i do this ?

My coding

```
//this ajax is called every minute
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'serverpage', 
            data: ({pid:1}),
            success: function(msg) { 

                var array = msg.split('/');
                if(array[0]==1){
                setTimeout(function() {  trigger(msg);          },array[1]+'000');
             }
            }

        }); 


//and my trigger function
function trigger(value)
{
    alert("i am triggered !");
}
```

**server response maybe**

**1/2** or **1/5** or **1/ 10** or **1/1**

here 1/**3(this is converted into seconds)**

Comment: `array[1]+'000'`? You deserve being slapped with a stick for that. `parseInt(array[1], 10)*1000` would be the proper way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you should fire the ajax call in your trigger function, or on the error callback. Fire it once at page ready, and then fire it when your success function is called.

```
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'serverpage', 
        data: ({pid:1}),
        success: function(msg) { 
            var array = msg.split('/');
            if(array[0]==1){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    trigger(msg);
                    ajaxCall();
                }, parseInt(array[1])*1000);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            setTimeout(ajaxCall, 1000);
        }
    }); 
}

$(ajaxCall);
```

Note: you should reply with some json instead of your custom data format "1/3". Something like "{success:1,delay:3}" would be much more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice . i got result ... i don't know how to trigger that error handler . so i used 0 status from server .... many thanks for idea

Comment: The **error** callback is for ajax-related errors, not functional errors. You can't really fire it at will, it fires when something prevents the ajax call from succeeding : 4XX, 5XX, timeouts, internet unavailable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can call your ajax function recursively from your 'success' callback function or in your case better would be from trigger function.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having your AJAX call in a timer, just recall it after each execution of the `trigger` function.

```
//and my trigger function
function trigger(value)
{
    alert("i am triggered !");
    MyAjaxFunction();
}
```

You have to call it once too at page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    MyAjaxFunction();
});
```